# Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать геометрическую прогрессию в c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Посмотрите код, а потом прочитайте вопрос, пожалуйста)

И так, чтобы не загружать память я решил все переменные товара выразить через одну *shopBonusLevel*, но беда в том, что с каждой покупкой переменная *ShopCosts* увеличивает в 1.3 раза(изначальная цена 33, потом она умножается на 1.3 и получается 43, потом уже нужно умножать 43 на 1.3, но как это сделать), понятно, что здесь нужна геометрическая прогрессия, но я пока что не могу догадаться, как ее реализовать в c#, поэтому прошу вас помочь мне)

**Как выразить** *ShopCosts* **через** *shopBonusLevel* **?**

мой отрезок кода

```
public void Helper()
{

        LittleLuckCount += 0.7;
        cash -= shopCosts;
        shopCosts *= 1.3; //это стоимость товара в магазине, с каждой его покупкой она увеличивается в 1.3 раза
        shopBttnsText.text = "$" + shopCosts;
        shopBonusLevel += 1;
        shopBttnsText.text = "Level: " + shopBonusLevel;

}
private void OnApplicationPause(bool _pause)
{        
if (!_pause)
{
    Load();          
}
else
{    
    Save();
}
}

private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    Save();
}

private void Save()
{


    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Bonus1", shopBonusLevel);



}

private void Load()
{


    shopBonusLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Bonus1");
    shopBttnsText.text = "Level: " + shopBonusLevel;
    LittleLuckCount = shopBonusLevel * 0.3;




}
```

Comment: Вы сначала другие свои вопросы закройте и отметьте верные ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

додумался)

```
shopCosts = System.Math.Round(33 * Math.Pow(1.3, shopBonusLevel), 0);
```